# Conversion of H.264 media file to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I have a raw h264 file which I want to convert to mp4 format so that I can play them in any video player.But I am getting many errors when I use ffmpeg for this task.
I have used the following command line to convert to mp4.

```
ffmpeg -f h264 -i input.264 -vcodec output.mp4
```

Below are the errors I get.

```
missing picture in access unit with size 3273224
no frame
decoding for stream 0 failed
could not find codec parameters for stream 0
```

When I probe using `ffprobe input.264` I get these errors.

```
Missing picture in access unit with size 3273224
No start code found
Error splitting the input into NAL units
decoding for stream 0 failed
could not find codec parameters for stream 0
```

I have checked other similar problems in this site but could not find the solution.I have added the file at http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=81246308569166574331

Have a look at the video.

Comment: Probably because this is not a programming question, so it is offtopic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bitstream file contains corrupt data (no data at all, all bytes are zero). Just take a look at it in your favourite hex editor, or using `hexdump` like this:

```
hexdump -C seq1_cam09_20150114_063257_500.264
```

which gives the following output:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
* 
0031f200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00                           |........|
0031f208
```

This is why you have `No start code found` message, since there are no NAL units (which usually start with `00 00 01`).

Comment: Thank you for having a look.

Comment: NAL units **always** start with `00 00 01`. The additional `00` is inserted before the start code if the NALU is the first NAL of the first access unit or if the NALU contains a parameter set @vcone

Comment: @incBrain what about SPS and PPS if they are being sent in bound, should the start code be 3 or 4 Bytes long? (I'm depacketizing RTP with h264 payload and there is no start code there)

Comment: @PawelK NAL units which contain paremeter sets must include an additional zero_byte. You can read about it in the spec (Annex B): ***When one or more of the following conditions are true, the zero_byte syntax element shall be present: – The nal_unit_type within the nal_unit( ) syntax structure is equal to VPS_NUT, SPS_NUT or PPS_NUT***

Comment: @incBrain you are right thanks, late evening isn't the right time for reading with understanding of such things. Just to be sure in layman's words the stream should look like this (without any leading an trailing zeroes):
`00000001[SPS]00000001[PPS]00000001[IFrame]000001[P/B-Frame]` and so on?

Comment: @PawelK its correct but do not forget that also every first NALU of new AU should have an additional zero_byte as well